# Передача функции, как аргумент

Tags: c++

ExpressionController.h:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "Value.h"

class ExpressionController {
private:
    std::vector<Value(*)(std::vector<std::string>)> functions;
    void registerFunction(Value(*f)(std::vector<std::string>));

    Value intEval(std::vector<std::string>);
    Value doubleEval(std::vector<std::string>);
    Value stringEval(std::vector<std::string>);

public:
    Value run(int, std::vector<std::string>);
    void init();
};
```

ExpressionController.cpp:

```
#include "ExpressionController.h"

Value ExpressionController::intEval(std::vector<std::string> params) {
    return Value(params[0], 0);
}

Value ExpressionController::doubleEval(std::vector<std::string> params) {
    return Value(params[0], 1);
}

Value ExpressionController::stringEval(std::vector<std::string> params) {
    return Value(params[0], 2);
}

void ExpressionController::registerFunction(Value(*f)(std::vector<std::string>)) {
    functions.push_back(f);
}

Value ExpressionController::run(int number, std::vector<std::string> args) {
    return functions[number](args);
}

void ExpressionController::init() {
    //registerFunction(intEval);
    //registerFunction(doubleEval);
    //registerFunction(stringEval);

}
```

При вызове трех последних закоментированных функций, появляется такая ошибка:

```
Аргумент типа Value(ExpressionController::*)(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>> params) 
не совместим с параметром типа Value(*)(std::vector<std::string, std::allocator<std::string>>)
```

В чем ошибка? Заранее спасибо

Comment: вы передаете не просто указатель на функцию, а передаете указатель на функцию член класса(не одно и тоже)

Comment: @ARHovsepyan И как же мне сделать так, что бы я мог передать эти функции в reigsterFunction?

Comment: передайте в reigsterFunction указатель на функцию_член, Value(ExpressionController::*)(std::vector<std::string>), ну а по хорошему не вижу полезность этой функции

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Новая ошибка появляется. Ладно, спасибо вам, но напишу еще один костыль :(

Comment: нужно, чтобы еще и ваш вектор содержал указатели на функцию_член

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена посредством вынесения данных трех методов, за пределы класса. Может быть кому-нибудь будет полезно:

ExpressionController.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include "Value.h"

class ExpressionController {
private:
    std::vector<Value(*)(std::vector<std::string>)> functions;
    void registerFunction(Value(*f)(std::vector<std::string>));

public:
    Value run(int, std::vector<std::string>);
    void init();
};
```

ExpressionController.cpp:

```
#include "ExpressionController.h"

Value intEval(std::vector<std::string> params) {
    return Value(params[0], 0);
}

Value doubleEval(std::vector<std::string> params) {
    return Value(params[0], 1);
}

Value stringEval(std::vector<std::string> params) {
    return Value(params[0], 2);
}

void ExpressionController::registerFunction(Value(*f)(std::vector<std::string>)) {
    functions.push_back(f);
}

Value ExpressionController::run(int number, std::vector<std::string> args) {
    return functions[number](args);
}

void ExpressionController::init() {
    registerFunction(intEval);
    registerFunction(doubleEval);
    registerFunction(stringEval);
}
```

Comment: ничего полезного, вы просто функции_члены сделали обычными функциями, что и требуется аргументу

Comment: С тем же успехом можно было бы сделать функции статическими.